# Unable to print a char array in loadrunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am trying to read a string from LR parameter and printing it character by character, but somehow, LR is rendering garbage chars. Can someone please check my code:

```
char str1[]="";
int len = 0;
int i =0;
char temp[]="";
sprintf(str1,"%s",lr_eval_string("{input}"));
lr_output_message("The message i got is %s",str1);

len=strlen(str1);
lr_output_message("The length of the message is- %d",len);

while(str1[i]!='\0')
{
    lr_output_message("Here is value being read %c",str1[i]);

    temp[0]=str1[i];
    temp[1]='\0';
    lr_output_message("Here is the value of temp -%s",temp);

    temp[0]='\0';
    i++;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Starting action Action.
Action.c(8): The message i got is testing
Action.c(12): The length of the message is- 7
Action.c(17): Here is value being read t
Action.c(21): Here is the value of temp -t
Action.c(17): Here is value being read e
Action.c(21): Here is the value of temp -e
Action.c(17): Here is value being read s
Action.c(21): Here is the value of temp -s
Action.c(17): Here is value being read 
Action.c(21): Here is the value of temp -
```

Comment: This type of item is common as a test of your C skills as part of employment screen.

Answer (score 1):

managed to resolve it after removing the initialisation part and assiging a size.
Here's the updated code.

```
char str1[10];
int len = 0;
int i =0;
char temp[10];
sprintf(str1,"%s",lr_eval_string("{input}"));
lr_output_message("The message i got is %s",str1);

len=strlen(str1);
lr_output_message("The length of the message is- %d",len);

while(str1[i]!='\0')
{
    lr_output_message("Here is value being read %c",str1[i]);

    temp[0]=str1[i];
    temp[1]='\0';
    lr_output_message("Here is the value of temp -%s",temp);

    temp[0]='\0';
    i++;
}
```